# How place floatingactionbutton on end of layout

Tags: android-layout, floating-action-button

I wanna place my floatingactionbutton on the end from the bottom of a relativelayout. How i do this as best and most practical?

Here's a screenshot, how it should look:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality only works when your parent layout is a coordinator layout.This can be achieved using the `app:layout_anchor=""` and the `app:layout_anchorGravity=""`

Some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff"
    >
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:id="@+id/appBar"
        >
    <!-- Put your content that is supposed to be in the appbar here -->

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable_resource_file"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom|start"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent layout is Relative Layout.
Just use

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/myFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_sign"
    app:elevation="4dp"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide your xml file for more reference

Comment: i have no xml directly for that problem ^^
i just need it as it is on the screenshot i attached on my question